# How to migrate a dockerized SQL Server database that uses a custom port to Azure SQL

Tags: azure, docker, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2017

I am hosting a bunch of micro-services and bot apps using Docker, and Azure virtual machines. There´s also a dockerized SQL Server 2017 instance in the stack, which I would like to migrate to Azure SQL. I am out of luck when trying to configure the source database in an Azure Database Migration project...

I tried to specify the service endpoint including the exposed port (since the dockerized SQL Server container´s public port is not 1433). I can connect to the SQL Server instance using SSMS from my workstation with no error, so connectivity is not the problem at all; does the Azure Database Migration require port 1433, or if not, how can I correctly specify a different port?

These are the error details I got from source details configuration in the Azure portal:

> Error Type
>   Failed to connect, please check error details
>
> Error Detail
>   Collector 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Advisor.SqlQueries.Contracts.Models.IQueryServerProperties' failed to collect data. A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>   The parameter is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source database configuration wizard is not very clear about the format of the remote server´s DNS name. Just specifying the fully qualified DNS name and port is not enough; it must contain the server´s instance name as well.

**Wrong:**

```
<DNS-name>,<port>
```

**Correct:**

```
<DNS-name>\<INSTANCENAME>,<port>
```